# For each pixel of an image what pixel value would it have?

Tags: php, image, rgb, pixel

I have separated the RGB channels of an image and converted them to YCbCr. Now what pixel value would each pixel have?

Comment: same, if you haven't done any transformations, because YCbCr is just another color representation and there are many of them. Conversion to other color spaces is done because sometimes it's more easy to make _some_ color transformations in them (than in RGB)

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas but that gives me a vector of 3 values. I need to check if the pixel value is odd or even? how would I do that then?

Comment: Pixel values in YCrCb is done by a wieghted average or RGB channels. Fist one Y corresponds to the gray value  and Y=0.299R+0.587G++0.114B. But I am not sure the parity of the pixel has any significance. +/- 1 in pixel value is visually unsignificant.

Comment: @Mrnd What you mean by saying "pixel value" - rgb 24-bit int value, rgba 32-bit int value, r/g/b channel 1 byte value, averaged intensity value (r+g+b)/3 or something different ? Simply just choose your "pixel value" definition and check if it is even by computing `value % 2 == 0` expression